# Could any non-zero entire function be constantly zero on $(0,\infty)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Could any non-zero entire function $f$ be constantly zero on positive half real axis $(0,+\infty)$? I know if such $f$ is bounded over $\mathbb{C}$, Liouville's theorem says that it should be constantly zero over $\mathbb{C}$. I am just wondering what if it is not bounded over $\mathbb{C}$. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem ?

Comment: @MartinR : The identity theorem as stated in that Wikipedia article refers to an open set in the plane. Then interval $(0,\infty)$ is not an open set in the plane.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: And later in that article: *"Specifically, if two holomorphic functions f and g on a domain D agree on a set S which has an accumulation point c in D then f = g on all of D"*

Answer (score 1):

Zeros of non-constant holomorphic functions are isolated, so no.

Comment: Many thanks! Any reference for this?

Comment: @Yanhg Any textbook in complex analysis. It's a straight-forward consequence of power series representations.